# How to discover a proof of this inequality? $(a,b,c)>(1,1,1) \implies abc+ \frac 1 a +\frac 1 b + \frac 1 c > a+b+c+\frac 1 {abc}$

Tags: inequality, soft-question, intuition

An exercise in the book Inequalities Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems by Zdravko Cvetkovski: If $a,b,c$ are real numbers greater than $1$ then $abc+ \frac 1 a +\frac 1 b + \frac 1 c > a+b+c+\frac 1 {abc}$. After struggling to prove it by myself, i peeked at the proof. It follows trivially from the inequality $$(a-\frac1 b)(b-\frac1 c)(c-\frac 1 a)>0.$$

How would one find a proof of inequality by themselves? It feels like it falls from the sky, but this book is aimed at high school students so i'm concerned about my failure to solve it by myself...

Comment: @MartinR question edited to clarify.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2721266/42969.

Comment: Another solution. For fixed $b$ and $c$, consider $f(a) = abc+ \frac 1 a +\frac 1 b + \frac 1 c - (a+b+c+\frac 1 {abc})$. What can you tell about $f'(a)$?

Answer (score 1):

That solution is most unnatural. Just get rid of denumerators and move everything to the left side and we get an expression

$$E =a^2b^2c^2 +ab+bc+ca-abc(a+b+c)-1$$

We need to prove $E>0$:
\begin{align}
E &= a^2bc(bc-1)+(bc-1)-ab(bc-1)-ac(bc-1)\\
&=(bc-1)\Big( a^2bc+1-ab-ac\Big)\\
&=(bc-1)\Big( ab(ac-1)-(ac-1)\Big)\\
&=(bc-1)(ac-1)(ab-1)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Note that if you set $x=1+u,\ y=1+v,\ z=1+w$ with $u,v,w>0$ then $E=3uv^2w+2u^2v^2w+2uvw+2uv^2w^2+u^2v^2w^2+3uvw^2+2u^2vw^2+3u^2vw+uv^2+u^2v+u^2v^2+vw^2+v^2w+v^2w^2+uw^2+u^2w+u^2w^2>0$ there are all $+$ signs and u,v,w positive. It is ugly but at least you don't have to guess the factorization, so in a sense it is easier.

Comment: Actually that factorization was nothing special. @zwim